# Close current window shortcut

Tags: keyboard

Is there a shortcut to close the current window?

1. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> closes the current *tab*
2. <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> closes *all* windows
3. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> quits the app completely

However, I’m looking for an intermediate between 1 and 2, to close the current window as if I’m pressing the red `x`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To close the current window with several tabs use:

<kbd>⇧/shift</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>

This works fine at least in Finder, Safari, Firefox and Google Chrome.